# Set up responsive style sheet in less?

Tags: css, responsive-design, less

I would like to set up a responsive skin suing less. But I would like to use rems for mobile and px for desktop.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use rem for both?

Comment: use fallback then: `{font-size:18px;font-size:1.125rem}`. Since your are doing it in less you can write a mixin which calculates both values for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using less, you don't necessarily need to distinguish those, you can just use the fallback notation via a mixin:

```
// the size of your base element
@base-size: 16px;

div {
    .font-size(18px);
} 

.font-size(@size){
  font-size: unit(@size,px);
  font-size: unit(@size/@base-size,rem);
}
```

compiles to:

```
div {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```